# How to get Windows Admin Center working with workgroup PC's

Tags: winrm

Trying to get Windows Admin Center working on my home network I ran into a few errors

1. Trying to add the computer

> A computer with the name 'pc1' was not automatically
>   discovered. You can still add it to your connections list, but its
>   availability cannot be verified.

2. Ignoring that and continuing, it still didn't want to work

> Connecting to remote server pc1 failed with the following error
>   message : WinRM cannot process the request. The following error with
>   error code 0x8009030e occurred while using Negotiate authentication: A
>   specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been
>   terminated. This can occur if the provided credentials are not valid
>   on the target server, or if the server identity could not be verified.
>   If you trust the server identity, add the server name to the
>   TrustedHosts list, and then retry the request. Use winrm.cmd to view
>   or edit the TrustedHosts list. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts
>   list might not be authenticated. For more information about how to
>   edit the TrustedHosts list, run the following command: winrm help
>   config. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
>   Help topic.

Answer (score 6):

After a bit of googling these are the steps from an elevated PowerShell session

## Managing PC

```
Set-Item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -Value pc1,pc2
```

where *pc1, pc2* are the names of the remote PCs

## Managed PC

```
Enable-PSRemoting -force
winrm quickconfig
```

With any luck, that is all you need to do.

### Public / Private Network

If you get this error

> WinRM firewall exception will not work since one of the network
>   connection types on this machine is set to Public. Change the network
>   connection type to either Domain or Private and try again.

Then find the name of the offending network

```
Get-NetConnectionProfile
```

and set it to private (if that makes sense security wise)

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -name "Unidentified network" -NetworkCategory Private
```